# How do I change shape of Extended Floating Action Button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, floating-action-button, material-components-android

I am trying to change the shape of my action button from this default shape to a rectangle. Here is my xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:cornerRadius="90dp"
        android:text="@string/create_player_text"
        android:fontFamily="@font/proximanova_semibold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.99"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.01"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Why not a simple MaterialButton?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti materialButton doesn't have hide and show method when I need to add it in scrollview

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to change the shape of the `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` you can use the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute in the layout:

```
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlayExtended"
        ../>
```

With:

```
  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlayExtended" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">0dp</item>
  </style>
```

If you want a corner radius just change the value in the `<item name="cornerSize">0dp</item>`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think Material Button would fit perfectly regarding to your needed, also Material Button have rectangular shape with small radius in corners. You should try it instead using Extended Floating Action Button.

Check the Official document how to use it with guidelines

[Material Button](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/)

Answer (score 0):

Create an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/_100sdp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and use it in ur extended fab - use with `shapeAppearanceOverlay`

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@drawable/bg_circle_black"
            android:text="Sign in to setup follow page"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/scrollView"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center|center_horizontal" />
```